# Is it possible to configure the fortify jenkins plugin to break the build when there are new findings?

Tags: jenkins, fortify

I am trying to configure the jenkins job that does the fortify scan to break if there are new findings reported with the following break condition:

[fortify priority order]:high category:Log Forging

But it breaks even if the findings are audited and marked as false positives. I want the build to break only if new un-audited findings are found during the scan.

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: I just put the fail condition [fortify priority order]:high category:Log Forging, but it fails if Fortify reports log forging findings, even if they are audited. Is there a way to tell the plugin to ignore audited findings?